# Angular, how toget form array values from nested form groups

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I need to get values inside of my form group, id don't know what my get function should say
This is the TS code

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
  import { FormGroup, FormArray, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms'


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent  {

  title = 'Nested FormArray Example Add Form Fields Dynamically';

  empForm:FormGroup;


  constructor(private fb:FormBuilder) {

    this.empForm=this.fb.group({
      employees: this.fb.array([]) ,
    })
  }


  employees(): FormArray {
    return this.empForm.get("employees") as FormArray
  }


  newEmployee(): FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group({
      firstName: '',
      lastName: '',
      skills:this.fb.array([])
    })
  }


  addEmployee() {
    console.log("Adding a employee");
    this.employees().push(this.newEmployee());
  }


  removeEmployee(empIndex:number) {
    this.employees().removeAt(empIndex);
  }


  employeeSkills(empIndex:number) : FormArray {
    return this.employees().at(empIndex).get("skills") as FormArray
  }

  newSkill(): FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group({
      skill: '',
      exp: '',
    })
  }

  addEmployeeSkill(empIndex:number) {
    this.employeeSkills(empIndex).push(this.newSkill());
  }

  removeEmployeeSkill(empIndex:number,skillIndex:number) {
    this.employeeSkills(empIndex).removeAt(skillIndex);
  }

  onSubmit() {
    console.log(this.empForm.value);
  }


}


export class country {
  id: string;
  name: string;

  constructor(id: string, name: string) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
  }
}
```

template

```
<h1>{{title}}</h1>

<form [formGroup]="empForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">

  <div formArrayName="employees">

    <div *ngFor="let employee of employees().controls; let empIndex=index">

      <div [formGroupName]="empIndex" style="border: 1px solid blue; padding: 10px; width: 600px; margin: 5px;">
        {{empIndex}}
        First Name :
        <input type="text" formControlName="firstName">
        Last Name:
        <input type="text" formControlName="lastName">

        <button (click)="removeEmployee(empIndex)">Remove</button>


        <div formArrayName="skills">

          <div *ngFor="let skill of employeeSkills(empIndex).controls; let skillIndex=index">



            <div [formGroupName]="skillIndex">
              {{skillIndex}}
              Skill :
              <input type="text" formControlName="skill">
              Exp:
              <input type="text" formControlName="exp">

              <button (click)="removeEmployeeSkill(empIndex,skillIndex)">Remove</button>

            </div>

          </div>
          <button type="button" (click)="addEmployeeSkill(empIndex)">Add Skill</button>
        </div>


      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

  <p>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </p>

</form>


<p>
  <button type="button" (click)="addEmployee()">Add Employee</button>
</p>
```

this gives value fro skills as an array containing, skill and exp values

```
 employeeSkills(empIndex:number) : FormArray {
    return this.employees().at(empIndex).get("skills") as FormArray
  }
```

But I need the value of skill and emp seperately, is there a way to get it?
I have tried it using

```
 employeeSkill(empIndex:number, empIndex2:number) : FormArray {
        return this. employeeSkills(empIndex).at(empIndex2).get("skills") as FormArray
      }
```

But it gived me error saying, cant get value of null

Comment: Angular version you are using ?

Comment: Angular 8.0 version

Comment: Can you reproduce the error in this [**`demo`**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bxrz3x)?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-a29jfx   I just added     console.log("skill is", this.getEmployeeSkills(0).value); in onSubmit() function, to display skill values after submit is pressed, but it shows undefined on the console @developer033

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the follwing gives you an array of the pairs of values that you need,

```
 employeeSkills(empIndex:number) : FormArray {
    return this.employees().at(empIndex).get("skills") as FormArray
  }
```

You could just parse the array and get the values out of there.

```
getEmployeeSkills(index: number){
    const employee  = this.empForm.value.employees[index]
    if (employee === undefined) return null
    return employee.skills.length ===0 ? null: employee.skills.map(skill => skill.skill)
  }
```

I built a little example for you here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3acuz7?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: I need the value to be displayed in my console.log too

Comment: when I type---  console.log("skill is", this.getEmployeeSkills(index).value);--in my ts file, there is a red line under the index and it says can not find index, please help

Comment: and when i write..console.log("skill is", this.getEmployeeSkills(0).value);..it says undefined in console page

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-a29jfx   I just added     console.log("skill is", this.getEmployeeSkills(0).value); in onSubmit() function, to display skill values after submit is pressed, but it show undefined on the console

Comment: The function in my post only returns the skill, not the value as your question was very unclear about that. If you want the value instead, use skill.value in the map.